# English equivalent of Argentine "persiana"

Tags: single-word-requests

While living in Argentina, I encountered a type of window blind system there called a "persiana."  It looked like this:

[image: Roller blind]

You tug on the nylon belt to the right to raise and lower the blinds, which are usually made of plastic.  There are holes between the slats to let the air through without letting in lots of light.  They are notorious for being difficult to operate and breaking often, as this one here (the case is missing, probably because we were trying to fix it).

Is there a word for this kind of blind system in English?  I thought about "louver" but that doesn't seem quite right (according to Google Images/Wikipedia).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for an English translation, while the site is meant for other way round questions.

Comment: You should ask this question either on ELU or ELL

Comment: They are called overhead doors in the states

Comment: @fedorqui Can I just flag this question to be moved?

Comment: As a side  note, it is called "persiana" also in Italian.

Comment: Possibly related to Persian blinds?

Comment: Actually, _persiana_ is any kind of window shutter — the complete name of this particular kind of window blind in Argentine Spanish is _persiana de enrollar_, literally _roller blind_ or _roller shutter_ as suggested by both answers below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's called a **roller shutter**.

> A **roller shutter**, **roller door** or **sectional overhead door** is a type of door or window shutter consisting of many horizontal slats (or sometimes bars or web systems) hinged together. The door is raised to open it and lowered to close it. On large doors, the action may be motorized. It provides protection against wind and rain. In shutter form, it is used in front of a window and protects the window from vandalism and burglary attempts.
>   [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roller_shutter)

Answer (score 5):

It looks like a "heavy duty", ie metal, kind of what I (in the UK) would call a **roller blind**.  These have a cord on one side which you can pull either side to lower or raise the blind.

[image]

Comment: Where did you get the pictures?

Comment: I just google image searched "roller blinds",

Answer (score 1):

"Persiana" was the word for the **window blinds** we had when we lived in Salamanca. It's the only word I ever learned for window blind.

One could develop photos in a room with the persianas rolled down. SO much better than anything I've found in the USA.

They used to be wood, but now are a kind of gray plastic.